# How to launch a single EC2 instance in response to an incoming network connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm planning to host some private services on AWS. These services will only be used by me and possibly 1-2 other people, but never more.

I would like the single EC2 instance that I'm using to only run when I'm using it. I don't want to manually start and stop it on the AWS console.

Ideally, I would need to things to happen:

1. Automatically shut down the single EC2 instance, if there have been no requests for the past hour.
2. Automatically start the instance, when there is an incoming request, i.e. I visit the URL of a service I'm hosting.

I've been able to configure a load balancer to shutdown the instance depending on incoming network traffic. I guess this is ok, if there is no better solution that can filter by IP region or number of incoming connections.

However, I can't figure out how to automatically launch an instance, just by visiting the corresponding URL. Is this even possible?

I could probably write a simple bash script to launch an instance, but I would prefer it to be automated.

Comment: As long as I know, you cannot do what you're asking for. The bash script is for sure the best (maybe unique) solution.

Comment: It's not possible. The instance would take way too long to start up and the request would be thrown away. Plus the load balancer will immediately return an error because it has no healthy servers to send the request to. You could create a script, or even an API Gateway endpoint that launches/starts your server. You could call that and wait a few minutes, and then start using your server.

Comment: @MarkB I wouldn't mind having to wait for the instance to launch or even the first request to fail, as long as it triggeret the launch.

Comment: @Jawap there's still nothing that is listening and handling that request except the load balancer, since you don't have any EC2 instances running. And a load balancer doesn't support the kind of thing you are asking for.

Comment: Depends on what type of service you're hosting but maybe host a static website on S3 (super cheap) and if you have any backend logic handle that through api gateway and lambda.